# Wordpress on GKE Click to Run- how to increase max upload file size

Tags: wordpress, google-kubernetes-engine

I’ve deployed the GKE click to run and need to increase the max upload file size. https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/wordpress

I see a ton of references to updating the php.ini or .htaccess, but I’m assuming this should be done via the YAML file in this deployment scenario.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap) with your custom configuration similar to this [link](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/10#issuecomment-88389890) to increase the size of the upload file size.

Then you need to go to your GKE workloads and in “wordpress-1-wordpress” workload of type “StatefulSet” you need to modify the YAML file where you can add the [ConfigMap data to a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume).

Another workaround is that, you can rebuild the image that you are using in a docker file.

Comment: Thanks Shamma.  As I worked through this, I decided moving away from the click to run solution was probably better for our scenario.  I've gone with https://github.com/stcox/gke-wordpress.  My issue now is that I just get "default backend - 404" when I hit the nginx url and don't see how I get it to serve up the wordpress site

Comment: This uses nginx ingress controller which runs off of a TCP LB (or service type LoadBalancer). That error is generated by the nginx ingress controller and usually means the host path is not properly configured